# problems with geoTiff file generation

Tags: python, gdal, qgis, geotiff

I am trying to make GeoTiff files and they should come out like this when viewed in qgis:

[image]

Unfortunately when the ones I have made come out like this when viewed in qgis:

[image]

without color.   Unfortunately the geoTiff I make is not viewable in many maps including leaflet.

Below is my code for in python for making geoTiff files from grib files:

How do I tweak my code in order to make a successful and viable geoTiff file?

```
import gdal
import osr
import sys

file=sys.argv[1]

print("file is ",file)

ds = gdal.Open("/home/jason/"+file+".grib2")
wind = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outRaster = driver.Create("/home/jason/"+file+".tiff", ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
outRaster.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())

outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(wind)
outband.SetMetadata({'name': 'wind'})

outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
outband.FlushCache()
```

Comment: A geotiff at it's core just stores the data, and doesn't necessarily represents a "pretty picture". Please clarify your question, is the image you show for example a RGB multiband, or is there a colortable attached etc. You can easily assign RGB values to the data and write it as you already do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing code that simply extracts a single band from a GRIB file, use `gdal_translate` which can do this with a few command-line options.

Problems like yours are almost always caused by bad interpretations of the values. First of all, weather organizations usually publish the wind as a sum of two vectors, `U` and `V` (wind along the meridians and along the parallels) that are expressed as floating point numbers.

Image rendering almost always expects integer values.

Try this:

`gdal_translate <input.grib> -b <input_band_number> -ot Byte -of GTiff -scale <output.tiff>`

The `-scale` option is very important as it will rescale the floating point values to integer values in the `-ot Byte` range - which is 0 to 255 and it is required for proper displaying.

You will also have to figure out what you are going to do with the `U` and `V` vectors. Wind is a vector, not a value.